# jQuery selector: Why is $("#id").find("p") faster than $("#id p")

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

The author of this page: http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck asserts that the jQuery selector
`$('#id').find('p')` is faster than `$('#id p')`, although that presumably produce the same results if I understand correctly.  What is the reason for this difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `$('#id').find('p')` is optimized to do...

```
document.getElementById('id').getElementsByTagName('p');
```

...whereas I'm guessing `$('#id p')` will either use `querySelectorAll` if available, or the JavaScript based selector engine if not.

---

You should note that performance always has variations between browsers. Opera is known to have an extremely fast `querySelectorAll`.

Also, different versions of jQuery may come up with different optimizations.

It could be that `$('#id p')` will be *(or currently is)* given the same optimization as the first version.

Comment: I assume that `querySelectorAll('#id p')` is pretty optimized as well. Performance differences should be tested, not asserted.

Comment: @Tomalak: I've done enough testing of `qSA` to know that in most browsers it is really quite slow in comparison. This isn't a random assertion. See my update regarding *Opera*.

Comment: I did not say that qSA would always be faster. I said *"I assume"* to prove my point, actually. After all, it is pretty difficult to support such a generalized statement one way or the other, given the wide differences in jQuery and browser versions.

Comment: I didn't say you said that. At least that wasn't my intention for pointing out my update. My point was/is that I was agreeing with you about the possibility of `qSA` optimization.

Answer (score 2):

It’s browser specific since jQuery uses `querySelectorAll` when it’s available. When I tested in WebKit it was indeed faster. As it turns out `querySelectorAll` is optimized for this case.

Inside WebKit, if the whole selector is `#<id>` and there is only one element in the document with that id, it’s optimized to `getElementById`. But, if the selector is anything else, `querySelectorAll` traverses the document looking for elements which match.

Yep, it should be possible to optimize this case so that they perform the same — but right now, no one has. You can find it [here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/dom/SelectorQuery.cpp?rev=104919#L84) in the WebKit source, `SelectorDataList::execute` uses `SelectorDataList::canUseIdLookup` to decide whether to use `getElementById`. It looks like this:

```
if (m_selectors.size() != 1)
    return false;
if (m_selectors[0].selector->m_match != CSSSelector::Id)
    return false;
if (!rootNode->inDocument())
    return false;
if (rootNode->document()->inQuirksMode())
    return false;
if (rootNode->document()->containsMultipleElementsWithId(m_selectors[0].selector->value()))
    return false;
return true;
```

If you were testing in a non-WebKit browser, it’s possible that it is missing similar optimizations.